# Create table of means and (standard deviations) for multiple variables, by groups, formatted for publication

Tags: r, data.table, knitr, r-markdown, aggregation

I am learning R. I want to produce a summary statistics table for a publication using simple, readable R code. The table should have the variables as rows, alternating mean and SD as columns, with two grouping variables also as columns. All values should be rounded to two digits, including zeros (adding zeros if necessary).

Using the mtcars dataset as an example, I want the table to look like this comparing 4, 6, and 8 cylinder cars, automatic or manual):

```
|     |4 0       |        |4 1       |        |6 0       |        |6 1       |        |8 0       |        |8 1       |        |
|:----|:---------|:-------|:---------|:-------|:---------|:-------|:---------|:-------|:---------|:-------|:---------|:-------|
|     |mean      |(SD)    |mean      |(SD)    |mean      |(SD)    |mean      |(SD)    |mean      |(SD)    |mean      |(SD)    |
|mpg  |22.90     |(1.45)  |28.07     |(4.48)  |19.12     |(1.63)  |20.57     |(0.75)  |15.05     |(2.77)  |15.40     |(0.57)  |
|disp |135.87    |(13.97) |93.61     |(20.48) |204.55    |(44.74) |155.00    |(8.66)  |357.62    |(71.82) |326.00    |(35.36) |
|hp   |84.67     |(19.66) |81.88     |(22.66) |115.25    |(9.18)  |131.67    |(37.53) |194.17    |(33.36) |299.50    |(50.20) |
```

I wrote the following code, but I still need to create the first two rows, and add the parentheses to the SD columns. To make the table pretty for publication, I used R Markdown, knitr, and kable. Is there a simpler, more standard, or more idiomatic way to do it?

````
```{r Create-Table-1}
library(data.table)
library(knitr)

mtcars_dt <- data.table(mtcars)
myGroups <- c("cyl", "am")
myVariables <- c("mpg", "disp", "hp")

means_dt <- mtcars_dt[,lapply(.SD, mean), .SDcols = myVariables, by = myGroups]
means_dt.melted <- melt.data.table(means_dt, id.vars = myGroups, measure.vars = myVariables)
means_dt.melted$stat <- "mean"

sd_dt <- mtcars_dt[,lapply(.SD, sd), .SDcols=myVariables, by=myGroups]
sd_dt.melted <- melt.data.table(sd_dt, id.vars = myGroups, measure.vars = myVariables)
sd_dt.melted$stat <- "sd" 

means_sd_merged_dt <- rbindlist(list(means_dt.melted, sd_dt.melted))
means_sd_dt <- dcast.data.table(means_sd_merged_dt, variable ~ cyl + am + stat, value.var = "value")

kable(means_sd_dt, digits = 2)

```
````

This is the table the code produces. The "8_1_mean" column is not rounded correctly. I tried pander, but it cannot add zeros.

```
|variable | 4_0_mean| 4_0_sd| 4_1_mean| 4_1_sd| 6_0_mean| 6_0_sd| 6_1_mean| 6_1_sd| 8_0_mean| 8_0_sd| 8_1_mean| 8_1_sd|
|:--------|--------:|------:|--------:|------:|--------:|------:|--------:|------:|--------:|------:|--------:|------:|
|mpg      |    22.90|   1.45|    28.07|   4.48|    19.12|   1.63|    20.57|   0.75|    15.05|   2.77|     15.4|   0.57|
|disp     |   135.87|  13.97|    93.61|  20.48|   204.55|  44.74|   155.00|   8.66|   357.62|  71.82|    326.0|  35.36|
|hp       |    84.67|  19.66|    81.88|  22.66|   115.25|   9.18|   131.67|  37.53|   194.17|  33.36|    299.5|  50.20|
```

---

UPDATE:
One of the main reasons I posted this question was to see if there's a simpler and easier way to make this kind of table, using other libraries, and programming best practices.

However, chinsoon12 provided an answer that works, which I incorporated into my first function in R. I'm updating here so other people can modify and use the function. It still has a bug I can't pin down with digits and/or nsmall, where sometimes a subgroup will have one more digit than specified.

```
tabulatemsg <- function(variables, groups, input_dt, round_digits = 2, na.rm = FALSE) {
  # Create a table of alternating means and (SDs), for the specified variables, with groups as columns.
  require(data.table)

  # Aggregate means
  means_dt <- input_dt[,lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm = na.rm), .SDcols = variables, by = groups]
  means_dt.melted <- melt.data.table(means_dt, id.vars = groups, measure.vars = variables)
  means_dt.melted$stat <- "mean"

  # Aggregate standard deviations
  sd_dt <- input_dt[,lapply(.SD, sd, na.rm = na.rm), .SDcols=variables, by=groups]
  sd_dt.melted <- melt.data.table(sd_dt, id.vars = groups, measure.vars = variables)
  sd_dt.melted$stat <- "sd" 

  # Merge and cast
  means_sd_merged_dt <- rbindlist(list(means_dt.melted, sd_dt.melted))
  means_sd_dt <- dcast.data.table(means_sd_merged_dt, paste("variable", 
    paste(c(groups, "stat"), collapse=" + "), sep=" ~ "), value.var = "value")

  # Ensure there are the specified number of digits after the decimal
  cols <- setdiff(names(means_sd_dt), "variable")
  means_sd_dt[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, format, digits=round_digits, nsmall=round_digits, justify="none"), .SDcols=cols]
  means_sd_dt[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, trimws), .SDcols=cols]

  # Add in parentheses
  cols <- names(means_sd_dt)[seq(3, ncol(means_sd_dt), by=2)]
  means_sd_dt[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) paste0("(", x, ")")), .SDcols=cols]

  # Add in second row
  output_table <- rbindlist(list(
    data.table(t(c("", rep(c("Mean", "(SD)"), (ncol(means_sd_dt)-1)/2)))),
    means_sd_dt), use.names=FALSE)

  # Rename first row
  setnames(output_table, colnames(output_table), 
    gsub("variable", "", (gsub(" sd","", (gsub(" mean", "", (gsub("_"," ", colnames(means_sd_dt)))))))))

  return(output_table)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert each column into character class using `format` so that you can ensure that there are 2 digits after decimal places and then, add in your parentheses

```
#ensure there are 2 digits after decimal
cols <- setdiff(names(means_sd_dt), "variable")
means_sd_dt[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, format, digits=2, nsmall=2L, justify="none"), .SDcols=cols]
means_sd_dt[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, trimws), .SDcols=cols]

#add in parentheses
cols <- names(means_sd_dt)[seq(3, ncol(means_sd_dt), by=2)]
means_sd_dt[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) paste0("(", x, ")")), .SDcols=cols]

#add in first row
outputTbl <- rbindlist(list(
    data.table(t(c("", rep(c("mean", "(SD)"), (ncol(means_sd_dt)-1)/2)))),
    means_sd_dt), use.names=FALSE)

kable(outputTbl, digits = 2)
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you! I figured out how to fix the column names row as well.  

    `#rename columns  
    setnames(outputTbl, colnames(outputTbl), gsub("variable", "", (gsub(" sd", "", (gsub(" mean", "", (gsub("_", " ", colnames(means_sd_dt)))))))))`

Comment: I want to make this a function so I can use it for various publications. Is there a way to fix the `means_sd_dt <- dcast.data.table(means_sd_merged_dt, variable ~ cyl + am + stat, value.var = "value")` line so that it refers to myCols instead of specifying them by hand?

Comment: Not in front of R now, check out 'as.formula'.

Comment: Thanks, that led me to [this page](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Formulas/Creating_a_formula_from_a_string/), from which I was able to get the corrected line: `means_sd_dt <- dcast.data.table(means_sd_merged_dt, paste("variable", paste(c(myGroups, "stat"), collapse=" + "), sep=" ~ "), value.var = "value")`